# Como clonar um elemento criado dinamicamente com jquery?

Tags: jquery, clone

Preciso de ajuda para clonar um elemento já criado dinamicamente com Jquery e somar +1 no 'value' e no 'name' do elemento.

```
else if(valorSelect == 'listaSuspensa'){
$(this).parents(".questionario").find('.divResposta').html(
'<div class="divListaSuspensa">'+
'<ol>'+
'<div class="NomearOpcaoLS">'+

  '<li><input class="w3-
   input w3-left" type="text" name="txtMultiplaEscolha" value="Opção 1" 
   style="width:90%">'+                     
  '<a id="id_ExcluirRespostaLS" class="excluirLS w3-
   right w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" style="color: grey;"><i 
   class="material-icons">close</i></a></li><br><br>'+

  '<li><a class="AddQtdLS">Adicionar opção</a></li>'+

'</div>'+
'</ol>'+
'</div>'

);
```

O elemento que eu gostaria de clonar é a primeira 'li', e adicionar logo abaixo.

Comment: $('.NomearOpcaoLS > li:first-child').clone().appendTo('.NomearOpcaoLS'); $('.NomearOpcaoLS > li:last-child > input').attr('id', 'NewID').val('XYZ');

Comment: Funcionou, só que no caso eu vou ter outras divs com os mesmos elementos então como faço para clonar somente na div que estou?

Answer (score 1):

Bem, se eu fosse precisar de um html sempre e alterar só uns valores, usaria um "template" ou html estático.
Algo como:

```
html = '<li>';
html += '<input class="w3-input w3-left" type="text" name="txtMultiplaEscolha" value="!value" style="width:90%">';
html += '<a id="id_ExcluirRespostaLS" class="excluirLS w3-right w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" style="color: grey;">';
html += '<i class="material-icons">close</i>';
html += '</a>';
html += '</li>';

$(".ul-append").append(html.replace("!value", "Opção 1"));
$(".ul-append").append(html.replace("!value", "Opção 2"));
```

Porque você já tá montando sua li no js mesmo, então, sem problema atribuir pra uma variável pra depois usar a mesma estrutura, não?

Mas, se tu quisesse clonar um elemento que já estaria renderizado, supomos:

```
<div class='div-para-clonar'><p>Div para clonar </p></div>
```

Poderia usar:

```
var cloneDaDiv = $(".div-para-clonar").clone();
```